# Is it possible to get 100% fire resistance?

Tags: diablo-ii, diablo-ii-resurrected

I recently saw [Hotspur](https://diablo2.io/uniques/hotspur-t821.html), which makes it possible to get 90% fire resistence. Is it possible to enhance this further to 100%? Or is there a "maximum" of the maximum fire resistence? And if so what would this mean for fire absorbtion? Will my characer constantly be heald during a fight against Diablo?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a maximum for Max Resistance at 95%:

> A character's default maximum resistance value is 75%, although certain Unique Items and the Paladin's Resistance Aura synergies can raise that number as high as 95%, the cap for resistances. Therefore, a character can never become totally immune to elemental attacks with resistance alone.

[source](https://diablo.fandom.com/wiki/Resistances)

The second way to reduce elemental damage - [Absortion](https://diablo.fandom.com/wiki/Absorption) - is calculated after resistance. It could be both % based and integer number based:

> Example: A player with Raven Frost and 75% Cold Resistance takes 400 hit points of cold damage. The 75% resistance takes the damage down to 100 HP. The Cold Absorb takes 20% of that figure off, leaving 80 HP, and then those 20 HP are converted to healing, leaving a final damage of just 60 HP.

It's worth noting that there are monsters with Conviction Aura, which reduces player resistances, it could be very dangerous. The aura looks like this:

[image: conviction aura]

As for fighting Diablo, not all of his attacks are Fire, the most iconic fire cone from his hands is actually Lightning. All of his elemental attacks:

> - Cold Touch: A melee attack that freezes the player.
> - Firestorm: Similar to the Druid's skill, but much larger and longer.
> - Fire Nova: Releases a ring of expanding flame that will envelop several screens.
> - Fire Wall: Identical to the Sorceress skill.
> - Red Lightning Hose: Also known as Lightning Inferno, this skill is without a doubt his deadliest. It works just like the Sorceress' Inferno, but has a longer reach and deals far more damage. Characters with inadequate resists and sub-par gear perish within seconds.

[source](https://diablo-archive.fandom.com/wiki/Diablo_(Diablo_II))

Comment: To sum it up: even if it would be possible to get 100% resistance, absorption would do nothing in that case.